# Can I normally distribute a variable of range between 0 and 1 with a heavy positive skew near 0?

Tags: math, normalization, distribution, normal-distribution, skew

I am trying to make my dependent variable normally distributed. Currently, it's positively skewed (massively) because of many 0 values. Using log results in many Infinites, and using log+1 creates exactly the same problem of many 0 values. Would there be another way?

[image]

Comment: Is your data actually continuous, or do you only have binned values as in your histogram?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The data is actually continuous!

Comment: Just to be clear, what are you actually looking for as a result? There are many different interpretations to your question. For instance do you want a normal distribution, but with the same variance as your current dataset, or what kind of transformations on the data are allowed?

Comment: Yes, the variance is important, so having a normal distribution with the same variance would be ideal. I have read about a box cox transformation, do you think it could help?

Comment: @Thomas Any idea still? Hoping for your thoughts...!